# How can i add a static block in the design---->page layout

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

i want to add a static block that consist of some formatted text
i want to add at the bottom of this code, but i dont know how to add the below static block content  `<h2><strong>Productos m&aacute;s Vendidos</strong></h2>`

and
**here is the code of my homepage:**

```
<reference name="header">
<block type="cms/block" name="header_slider">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>header_slider</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
<reference name="left">
 <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
 <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
 <remove name="tags_popular" />
 <remove name="right.poll" />
 <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
 <remove name="right.reports.product.compared" />
 <remove name="wishlist_sidebar" />
<block type="cms/block" name="side_banners">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>side_banners</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
        <action method="setProductsCount"><count>9</count></action> 
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
<action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
     <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

**The cms block i want to put will be here after this last `</reference>`**

what code should i use to add the statick block?

thanks

Comment: Where do you want the static block content to show? The SB content has to be rendered as a child of a block. Depending on which block, it may require modifying a template.

Answer (score 4):

In Cms Page Layout -->

```
 <reference name="right">
        <block type="cms/block" name="your_block_id_1_name" before="-">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>your_block_id_1</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="your_block_id_1_name" after="-">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>your_block_id_1</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

CMS Page Content -->

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="home_image-center"}}
```

In .phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_is')->toHtml();?>
```